# How get String from Unit in Android-Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, okhttp

I'm use Okhttp3 GET method to a Web service

```
val client= OkHttpClient()
    fun login_Chk(id:String,pw:String)
     {
       val req=Request.Builder()
               .url("https://www.hxxxxxx.com/WebService.asmx/Login_Check?ID=${id}&PW=${pw}")
               .build()
       client.newCall(req).enqueue(object : Callback{
        override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {}
        override fun onResponse(call: Call, res: Response) {
         println(res.body()?.string().toString())
            return
        }
       })
     }
```

I want check the webservice return its "Success" or "Fail"

downside its my Logcat 
https://images2.imgbox.com/b4/cb/bKfiHsgc_o.png

In c# we can use like

```
if(webservice(ID,PW) =="Success")
{
......
}
```

but in kotlin I dont know how to do.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't return from an asynchronous method like this. Plus a Unit method doesn't return anything anyway

You need to pass the Callback object through to the client from the method

```
fun login_Chk(id:String,pw:String, cb:Callback) 
  {
```

Then in the body just do this

```
client.newCall(req).enqueue(cb);
```

Wherever you call `login_Chk`, you define the Callback, which inside has `onResponse`, which is where data is "returned" to the calling method

You'll also need an XML parser. You can't do `== "Success"` with that response

Comment: Sorry sir,I don't know how to modify my code,Hava any simple? thanks

Comment: You have `fun login_Chk(id:String,pw:String)` already. So add the parameter, as shown. You also have `client.newCall(req).enqueue(...`, so use the parameter, as shown. The rest, I assumed you have actually tried to use `login_Chk` function somewhere

Comment: yes,at my MainActivity `Web_ServiceCall().login_Chk(Handid.text.toString(),Handpd.text.toString())`

Comment: Are you having errors when you try to add `object : Callback{ }` as a third parameter there?

Comment: No values passed for parameters 'cb'

Comment: Right, you have `Handid.text.toString()`, and `Handpd.te‌​xt.toString()`... You need to make a new `Callback`

Comment: It show callback must initialize,but I dont know what type is it

Comment: It's type is a `Callback`.... In your question you did `enqueue(object : Callback{` , and passed that parameter to the enqueue method. All I've done here is simply move that Callback object to be wrote somewhere else. It is defined the exact same way